# Anaconda3's python cannot find kerberos credential cache

Tags: python, sql-server, kerberos

I run into an error when creating an ODBC connection to a MSSQL server using Anaconda's version of Python 3:

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1918003883) (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The server has joined a Windows Active Directory domain and Kerberos realm via SSSD. I can SSH into the server, and retrieve a TGT using `kinit`. I can even see the credential cache with `klist`. But the python process cannot seem to either find the Kerberos TGT or the Kerberos credential cache.

**the setup:**

*python*

```
$ /mnt/ds/anaconda3/bin/python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

*test.py*

```
from pyodbc import connect
connection = connect('DSN=MyDSN')
```

*/etc/odbc.ini*

```
[MyDSN]
#Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description=MyMSSQL ODBC Driver
Trace=No
Server=MyMSSQL
Trusted_Connection=Yes
```

*/etc/odbcinst.ini*

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.1.so.0.1
UsageCount=1
```

*Red Hat Enterprise Linux*

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
$ uname -r
3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64
```

*msodbcsql17*

```
$ sudo yum info msodbcsql17
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Installed Packages
Name        : msodbcsql17
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 17.1.0.1
Release     : 1
Size        : 17 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : packages-microsoft-com-prod
Summary     : ODBC Driver for Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)
License     : https://aka.ms/odbc170eula
Description : This package provides an ODBC driver that can connect to Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R).
```

*unixODBC*

```
$ sudo yum info unixODBC
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Installed Packages
Name        : unixODBC
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.3.1
Release     : 11.el7
Size        : 1.2 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
Summary     : A complete ODBC driver manager for Linux
URL         : http://www.unixODBC.org/
License     : GPLv2+ and LGPLv2+
Description : Install unixODBC if you want to access databases through ODBC.
            : You will also need the mysql-connector-odbc package if you want to access
            : a MySQL database, and/or the postgresql-odbc package for PostgreSQL.
$ /mnt/ds/anaconda3/bin/conda list unixodbc
# packages in environment at /mnt/ds/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
unixodbc                  2.3.6                h1bed415_0
```

*pyodbc*

```
$ /mnt/ds/anaconda3/bin/conda list pyodbc
# packages in environment at /mnt/ds/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyodbc                    4.0.23           py36hf484d3e_0
```

**Here are some things I've tried:**

- Using Python-2.7.15, as packaged by Anaconda2. That worked!
- Using `isql`. I ran `isql MyDSN` and that connected.
- There are two unixODBC libraries (one installed via `yum`; the other with `conda`). By default, it will use `conda`'s, but I forced it to use the system unixODBC package with `LD_PRELOAD`. Same error.
- I tried downgrading the database driver to *msodbcsql-13.1.9.2-1* and then to *msodbcsql-13.0.1.0-1*. Same error.
- I tried swapping out PyODBC for TurbODBC, another Python ODBC library. Same error.
- I created a separate environment in `conda` with python-3.5. And that worked! Still not sure why.
- I wrote a simple C program that interfaced with unixODBC. That program was able to connect to the MSSQL server via Kerberos just fine.
- I ran the python2 positive test case and the python3 negative test case through `strace` to review the system calls. I thought that might reveal something. It seems that they both start looking for the *client.keytab* file on the file system. Then, in the postive test case, it will fallback to searching the kernel's keyring, where it will successfully find the credential cache and proceed. However, in the negative test case, it simply retries to find *client.keytab*, and never attempts to search the keyring.
- I enabled the unixODBC trace option, one with Python3 test case, and the other with Python2 test case. Unfortunately, the traces (shown below) don't reveal anything to me.

*py3-unixodbc.trace*

```
[ODBC][8741][1527046794.480751][__handles.c][460]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Environment = 0x55eea73ed130
[ODBC][8741][1527046794.480806][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
                Entry:
                        Environment = 0x55eea73ed130
                        Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
                        Value = 0x3
                        StrLen = 4
[ODBC][8741][1527046794.480824][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][363]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][8741][1527046794.480843][SQLAllocHandle.c][375]
                Entry:
                        Handle Type = 2
                        Input Handle = 0x55eea73ed130
[ODBC][8741][1527046794.480861][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Output Handle = 0x55eea7400500
[ODBC][8741][1527046794.481176][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x55eea7400500
                        Window Hdl = (nil)
                        Str In = [DSN=MyDSN][length = 15]
                        Str Out = (nil)
                        Str Out Max = 0
                        Str Out Ptr = (nil)
                        Completion = 0
                UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

[ODBC][8741][1527046794.575566][__handles.c][460]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Environment = 0x55eea746e360
[ODBC][8741][1527046794.575614][SQLGetEnvAttr.c][157]
                Entry:
                        Environment = 0x55eea746e360
                        Attribute = 65002
                        Value = 0x7ffd399177f0
                        Buffer Len = 128
                        StrLen = 0x7ffd3991778c
[ODBC][8741][1527046794.575632][SQLGetEnvAttr.c][264]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][8741][1527046794.575651][SQLFreeHandle.c][219]
                Entry:
                        Handle Type = 1
                        Input Handle = 0x55eea746e360
```

*py2-unixodbc.trace*

```
[ODBC][8746][1527046842.073439][__handles.c][460]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Environment = 0x185e2e0
[ODBC][8746][1527046842.073530][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
                Entry:
                        Environment = 0x185e2e0
                        Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
                        Value = 0x3
                        StrLen = 4
[ODBC][8746][1527046842.073552][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][363]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][8746][1527046842.073572][SQLAllocHandle.c][375]
                Entry:
                        Handle Type = 2
                        Input Handle = 0x185e2e0
[ODBC][8746][1527046842.073590][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Output Handle = 0x1857d40
[ODBC][8746][1527046842.073613][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x1857d40
                        Window Hdl = (nil)
                        Str In = [DSN=MyDSN][length = 15]
                        Str Out = (nil)
                        Str Out Max = 0
                        Str Out Ptr = (nil)
                        Completion = 0
                UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

[ODBC][8746][1527046842.208760][__handles.c][460]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Environment = 0x1967210
[ODBC][8746][1527046842.208830][SQLGetEnvAttr.c][157]
                Entry:
                        Environment = 0x1967210
                        Attribute = 65002
                        Value = 0x7ffe1153fcf0
                        Buffer Len = 128
                        StrLen = 0x7ffe1153fc8c
[ODBC][8746][1527046842.208849][SQLGetEnvAttr.c][264]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][8746][1527046842.208869][SQLFreeHandle.c][219]
                Entry:
                        Handle Type = 1
                        Input Handle = 0x1967210
```

Suffice it to say, I'm at my wit's end. *Any* ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

late reply but I hope someone will find it useful.

This very same issue for me was casued by the `krb5` package which was coexisting with the system-wide kerberos installation: removing it from the environment solved the problem (I tried to make it work but had no success).